# php allow only one period in a string

Tags: php, post, preg-replace

I have been working on this code for hours and I cant seem to make it work. I have an input field that allows users to submit a price for a certain item. Here is the desired process:

```
//Get the post it price and only allow numbers and one period|dot
$price = $_POST['price'];
$price = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#i', '', $_POST['price']);
```

So I only want to allow one period per string, so if the User inputs 100.00.00, it will correct that and remove the first period and convert it to 10000.00
After this I want to add a comma for every 3rd character as follows:
if the posted price is 10000.00 it will convert it to 10,000.00.
 Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = "100.00.00";

$array = explode(".", $string);

$last = array_pop($array);

echo number_format(implode("", $array)) . "." . $last;
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/t1WuGK